# No puedo acceder a tablas "en uso" en phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Hoy cuando he encendido el PC y he arrancado el Xampp he visto que hay ciertas tablas que me pone en uso y no puedo acceder a ellas ni repararlas si las selecciono.

Y da un error a acceder a ellas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo acceder a ellas o repararlas?

Gracias un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Hay múltiples posibilidades por las cuales pueden estar las tablas **"IN USE"**.
Uno de los problemas mas habituales es que se hayan corrompido de alguna forma o haya algun proceso que las bloquea.
En este caso prueba lo siguiente:

```
REPAIR TABLE `table_name`
```

_

En algunas situaciones, no importa cuántas veces se ejecuta `REPAIR`, la tabla todavía devuelve `EN USO` y lo peor es que el sistema dice *"ya actualizado"*.

Si tiene acceso `shell`, esto es lo que debe hacer:

```
$ cd /var/lib/mysql/DATABASE
$ myisamchk --safe-recover TABLE
```

Donde `DATABASE` es la que se está intentando arreglar.

Esto reparará la tabla en `safemode` y *DEBERÍA* resultar.

Answer (score -1):

bueno buscando en internet por la solucion de este problema(tabla: "en uso"), di con tu misma incertidumbre...bueno pues lo que yo hice fue, borrar la base de datos la cual esta alojada en 000webhost y posteriormento volvi a agregarla...y se soluciono, ademas no perdi los datos de las tablas...